# how to keep processed data with to_python when form is not valid?

Tags: django, forms

I have a django form which can be not valid, but I would like to keep the data processed with to_python() method on some fields to propose it to the user, so that he can changes wrong fields, but having already processed values for some 'good' fields.

```
f = MyForm(request.POST)
if f.is_valid():
    # not my case
return render_to_response('template.html', form)
```

and request.POST {'price':'100 000', 'duration':'aaa'}
is processed with to_python() to  {'price':'100000', 'duration':'aaa'}
and I would like to fill the form in render_to_response with this new price value (100000 and not 100 000)

Comment: Can't you just return the processed form like `return render_to_response('template.html', f)`?

Comment: no, because in this case, I can't have the price value processed with to_python() method, because form is not valid.